# How do i assign a specific node as a variable value without outputting it?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I only have 5 days of experience with MySQL so have not yet developed a natural understanding of the capabilities of the language.

I have created a database where a query is performed and output is generated as links which, when clicked, perform  another query in the database for all subcategories of the clicked node.

Up until now, i have literally been passing the name of the query onclick as a variable in order to allow for the next search.

i.e. if the user clicks on "health and fitness", the string "health and fitness" is literally passed via variable and plugged in to the next query.

However i have realized i need a more powerful method of transferring the appropriate data about each node from search to search.

i.e. if someone clicks on "health and fitness" i want to not only pass that string via url as a variable, but also pass other information related to that category, i.e. its id number and parent_id.

So essentially, whichever of several queries a user clicks on, i want to be able to send that query as a string, and its parent id through to the php page which will query and display data accordingly.

I'm thinking i should create a variable to hold the data i want which gets put in the onclick url on each repetition of the query results loop.

However I'm still not sure how to navigate databases or assign specific row/column values to a variable.

Comment: You only need to pass one unique thing... you can get the rest of the data when you query on that unique thing. This can be the numeric primary key or a unique "slug" whch is more human readable like `health-and-fitness`

Comment: So if i pass "health and fitness", then i want to derive the parent_id of health and fitness, how do i put that specific parent_id of health and fitness as a variable, so that i can manipulate it further?